# Automatic API wrapper/generator

Tags: api, generator

I am thinking about using the Galaxy Project as a front end for Lucene.  It's an introductory college course on search so not everyone has programming experience. Even with programming experience, it's not the implementation that really matters but the programmatic transformation of the data.  Galaxy provides a nice interface for explicit hypothesis testing using various configurations and data transforms.

We were working with the Get/REST/SOA interface + [Meemoo](http://meemoo.org/) and lots of JS, but we have to build everything from scratch.  But Galaxy's batching interface would allow us to extend the learning modules to the parser.

Anyway, Galaxy's various modules can interact via the command line and those modules are just [XML config files](http://wiki.g2.bx.psu.edu/Admin/Tools/Tool%20Config%20Syntax#A.3Ccommand.3E_tag_set):

```
<command interpreter="python">sorter.py -i $input -o $out_file1 -cols $column</command>
```

Are there any frameworks I could use to generate an XML file from the existing command line API?  I know I could do regex, but that would take about as long to build as just manually creating a subset of the API's...

Sorry if this is too basic, "automatic API wrapper" etc result in unsurprisingly poor search results :/

Thanks!